# How to check a .deb file Installable or not using command line

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

How can i check a *.deb file is good to install in current system without install it? Is there any way that i can use dpkg or apt-get or other command line tools for this purpose?

**Note:** I need to do this using command line(no gui or synaptic) and there may have multiple deb files.

```
if dpkg --check *.deb == True
   dpkg -i *.deb
else
   perror
```

Comment: `dpkg` has a `--dry-run` option, the output of which should tell you want you want by inspection, but without a lot of grep testing I don't think this answers your question by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You may like the lintian command which checks for common packaging errors. The link below may help you.

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/checkit.en.html

Comment: you can't check deb package directly using debi.

Answer (score 0):

To see the contents of a .deb file, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg-deb -c <file_name.deb>
```

To read the contents of a installed package:

```
sudo dpkg -L <package_name>
```

For more info see <sup>[Debian Help](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm)</sup>